# Why is this pointer arithmetic necessary to use the clone function in C?

Tags: c, linux, clone

I'm trying to use the `clone()` function in C, and am uncertain of how the second argument works.  Per the `clone()` man page:

```
   The child_stack argument specifies the location of the stack used by  the
   child  process.  Since the child and calling process may share memory, it
   is not possible for the child process to execute in the same stack as the
   calling  process.  The calling process must therefore set up memory space
   for the child stack and pass a pointer to this space to clone().   Stacks
   grow downwards on all processors that run Linux (except the HP PA proces‐
   sors), so child_stack usually points to the topmost address of the memory
   space set up for the child stack.
```

After following suggestions in the comments on [this article](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/5211), I've been able to get a simple example working using this C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define SIZE 65536

int v1;

int run(void *arg) {
  v1 = 42;
  return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  void **child_stack;
  int pid, rc, status;
  v1 = 10;
  child_stack = (void **) malloc(SIZE);
  assert(child_stack != NULL);
  printf("v1 before: %d\n", v1);

  pid = clone(run, child_stack + SIZE/sizeof(void **), CLONE_VM, NULL);
  //pid = clone(run, child_stack + SIZE, CLONE_VM, NULL);

  assert(pid != -1);
  status = 0;
  rc = waitpid(pid, &status, __WALL);
  assert(rc != -1);
  assert(WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0);
  printf("v1 after:  %d\n", v1);
  return 0;
}
```

But I'm confused as to why the particular pointer arithmetic in the `clone` line is necessary.  Given that according to the `clone` docs the stack is supposed to grow downward, I see why you should add a value to the pointer returned by `malloc` before passing it in.  But I'd expect that you'd add the number of bytes malloc'd, instead of that value divided by 8 (on a 64-bit system), which is what seems to actually work.  The code above seems to work fine regardless of what I define `SIZE` as, but if I use the commented version instead, which is what I'd expect to work, I get a segmentation fault for all SIZE values above a certain threshold.

So, anyone understand why the given `clone` line works, but the commented one doesn't?

As for why I'm using `clone` to begin with, instead of `fork` or pthreads, I'm trying to use some of its advanced sandboxing features to prevent an untrusted process from breaking out of a chroot jail, as described [here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pointer arithmetic, the size of the type pointed to is incorporated when determining the actual memory offset, take for example:

```
int a[2] = {1, 2};
int* p = a;

printf("%x: %x\n", &a[0], p);
printf("%x: %x\n", &a[1], p + 1);
```

In this case, the value of `p` isn't just address of `p` + 1, it's the value of `p + 1 * sizeof(int)` (the size of the type pointed to). To account for this, when you want to offset some number of bytes, you need to divide the offset by the size of the pointer type you're modifying. In your case, the type you're pointing to is `void*`, so it may be more accurate to say:

```
pid = clone(run, child_stack + SIZE/sizeof(void *), CLONE_VM, NULL);
```

You can visualize this behavior with something like:

```
int SIZE = 65536;
void** child_stack = (void **) malloc(SIZE);

void** child_stack_end = child_stack + SIZE;
void** child_stack_end2 = child_stack + SIZE / sizeof(*child_stack);

printf("%d\n", (intptr_t)child_stack_end - (intptr_t)child_stack); // "262144"
printf("%d\n", (intptr_t)child_stack_end2 - (intptr_t)child_stack); // "65536"
```

Comment: Why is `child_stack` of type `void**` and not `void*` ?

Comment: It doesn't need to be (any pointer type could be used). This was the type the original author was using, so it was continued here. As you pointed out in a another comment, `char*` seems like an easier type for this test case (since it avoids the sizeof() requirements).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've declared `child_stack` as a `void **` (a pointer to void pointers), when its really a pointer to raw memory to be used for a stack (which doesn't have a C type).  So it would make more sense if you just declared it as a `char *` or `intptr_t` instead, in which case you could do the pointer arithmetic directly (passing `child_stack + SIZE`) rather than having to correct for the incorrect type.

Note that the correction as written is incorrect (should be `/ sizeof(void *)` rather than `/ sizeof(void **)`), but it works out ok as `sizeof(void **) == sizeof(void *)` on most machines

Comment: This. I was wondering why the stack was declared as a `void**`. I could sorta understand `void*` but `char*` seems like the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an integer value V to a pointer of type T* increments the memory address by V*sizeof(T). Since `child_stack` in your code has type `void**`, `child_stack+SIZE` in effect means that the memory address is increased by `SIZE*sizeof(void*)` bytes.

Answer (score -1):

`child_stack + SIZE` points to one past the end of the end of the data you allocated, so a segmentation fault for using that location as the start of the stack is not that surprising. Have you tried `child_stack + SIZE - 1`?